# What are some interesting topological properties about the set of all convergent real sequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

Let C be the set of all convergent sequences in $\mathbb{R}$ under the product topology or uniform topology. So $C \subset \prod_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{R}$. For one, Hilbert's Cube $\prod_{n=1}^\infty \left[0,\frac{1}{n}\right]$ is contained in $C$.

Comment: There are several reasonable topologies on this set, so in order to discuss "topological properties" you'll have to specify which one you have in mind.

Comment: You're right. Edited post. I was thinking the natural topology for this space is the product topology of Euclidean space.

Comment: Well, in some ways the uniform topology is nicer and more natural; e.g. it's a separable commutative $C^*$-algebra.  The product topology, on the other hand, has some "interesting" but not so desirable properties; e.g. it's meager.

Answer (score 2):

Set $\ C\ $ is invariant under the continuous shift
$\ s:\prod_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb R\to\prod_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb R,\ $
where
$$ s(x_1\ x_2\ x_3\ \ldots)\ :=\ (x_2\ x_3\ x_4\ \ldots) $$

Furthermore, $\ s(C)=C.$

Answer (score 1):

Set $\ C\ $ is dense in $\ \prod_{n=1}^\infty\mathbb R.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\ \lim:C\to\mathbb R\ $ be the limit function (functional). Then

$$ \lim(G)\ =\ \mathbb R $$

for every non-empty open subset of the product space. It follows that the limit function is not continuous under the product topology.

Comment: That's interesting. I wonder if it's continuous under the uniform metric topology.

Comment: Yes. (Isn't it nice for a change? :) ).

Comment: Does this imply C is not complete under the product metric?